# Google App Engine error DeadlineExceededException

Tags: java, google-app-engine

The http request ( Or database connection ) is interrupted after 60 seconds, where it has been running without issues since years, this started to happen before couple of days after I deployed a new version of the application.

Config:
Java8
Instance class B4

Migrating back to the older version runs just fine ( same DB, same config,.. )

Some important parts of the exception:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
..
..
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (000001725d05624c) started at 2020/05/28 20:42:13.452 UTC and was still executing at 2020/05/28 20:43:14.119 UTC.
```

Comment: Could you provide more information? Does your DB CPU or RAM saturate? Does it happen on a specific functionality/request?

Comment: Figured it out. I will add the answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused from using the deprecated google maven plugin `com.google.appengine.appengine-maven-plugin` which fails silently and it does **not** update GAE configuration, and so the defaults ones are used, for example the instance class was `F1`.

Switched to maven plugin `com.google.cloud.tools.appengine-maven-plugin`.

More info about the plugin
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-maven#adding_the_app_engine_plugin_to_an_existing_project_optional